# How to append JSON value to an HTML attribute?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, json

I want to append one of my JSON object value to a HTML attribute value.  I am doing like this.
  `<div ng-messages="registrationForm.[contact.id].$error">`
Here `contact.id` is from a JSON object, and `registrationForm` is my HTML form name.
It doesn't work.

```
    <form name="registrationForm">
        <div data-ng-repeat="contact in users.contacts">
                <md-input-container class="md-block" flex="50">
                    <input required type="text" name="contact.id" ng-model="contact.name"/>
                    <div ng-messages="registrationForm.[contact.id].$error">
                        <div ng-message-exp="['required']">
                            {{ "print error msg here"}}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </md-input-container>
            </div>
</form>
```

How can I append `contact.id` with my form name "`registrationForm`". For eg: if contact.id is 10, I need "`registrationForm.10.$error`" as '`ng-messages`' value

Comment: `<div ng-messages="registrationForm[contact.id].$error">`

Answer (score 0):

you can use an angular expression in your attributes that aren't coming from angular, example:

name="{{contact.id}}"

Comment: how can I append {{contact.id}} with my form name "registrationForm". For eg: if contact.id is 10, I need "registrationForm.10.$error" as 'ng-messages' value

Answer (score 0):

You can use

[ng-form](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngForm)

Example:

HTML:

```
<form name="registrationForm">
    <div data-ng-repeat="contact in users.contacts">
        <ng-form name="registrationSubForm">
            <md-input-container class="md-block" flex="50">
                <input required type="text" name="contact_name" ng-model="contact.name" />
                <div ng-messages="registrationSubForm.contact_name.$error">
                    <div ng-message="required">
                        Required
                    </div>
                 </div>
            </md-input-container>
        </ng-form>
    </div>
</form>
```